# Android Observables.zip list observables

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I need to execute several parallel requests to the server to retrieve data. How can I do this using observables.
My implementation

```
public void get(String s, Observer<Boolean> observer) {
    APIService apiService = App.getApi();
    final Observable<User> oUser = apiService.getUser(Integer.valueOf(s));
    final Observable<List<DocType>> oDocType = apiService.getDocType();
    final Observable<List<TaskTypes>> oTaskTypes = apiService.getTaskType();
    final Observable<List<DocTaskLeave>> oTaskLeave = apiService.getTaskLeave();
    final Observable<List<DocStatus>> oDocStatus = apiService.getDocStatus();
    final Observable<List<DocPayment>> oDocPayment = apiService.getPaymentType();
    final Observable<List<DocCredit>> oDocCredit = apiService.getPaymentCredit();
    final Observable<List<ClientRegion>> oClientRegion = apiService.getClientRegion();
    final Observable<List<ProductRules>> oProductRules = apiService.getProductsRules();
    final Observable<List<ReportTypes>> oReportTypes = apiService.getReportType();
    List<Observable> observables = new ArrayList<>();
    observables.add(oUser);
    observables.add(oDocType);
    observables.add(oTaskTypes);
    observables.add(oTaskLeave);
    observables.add(oDocStatus);
    observables.add(oDocPayment);
    observables.add(oDocCredit);
    observables.add(oClientRegion);
    observables.add(oProductRules);
    observables.add(oReportTypes);
    Observable obs = Observable.zip(observables, new FuncN() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Object... args) {
            return null;
        }
    });
    obs.subscribe(observer);
}
```

I think that this is wrong because. IDE shows a warning.
[image]

Comment: Do you have to handle results all at once?

Comment: yes. i must saved result my local database.

Comment: I mean, can you put each result into db separately, as soon as it returns?

Comment: important to load when executing in parallel threads.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with `zip` would be ugly and verbose cause you have as many as 10 observables, each of different type. Also, you'll need to cast each result to its proper type before storing it into DB.

Since your goal is to fetch and store various pieces of data (as I can see), I would represent each task as a separate `Completable` that executes on its own `Scheduler`:

```
final Completable oUser = apiService.getUser(Integer.valueOf(s))
        .doOnNext(result -> /* save to db */) // or flatMap
        .toCompletable()
        .retry(3) // in case of upstream error - retries this task (up to 3 times)
        .onErrorComplete() // replaces upstream errors with onCompleted event
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

final Completable oDocType = apiService.getDocType()
        .doOnNext(result -> /* save to db */)
        .toCompletable()
        .retry(3)
        .onErrorComplete()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

// ... etc

Completable.merge(oUser, oDocType, oTaskTypes, oTaskLeave, oDocStatus, 
        oDocPayment, oDocCredit, oClientRegion, oProductRules, oReportTypes)
            .subscribe(new CompletableSubscriber() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    // all done!
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // handle error
                }

                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription d) {
                    // manage subscription if needed
                }
            });
```

All tasks execute in parallel. Also, you could set retry count for each request or any other additional logic.

Comment: If in one of the Observables occurs crash, will others continue to execute?

Comment: I need the others to complete the execution too.

Comment: If you add `onErrorComplete` operator to each task - then yes, they will continue its execution. I edited the answer.

Comment: When will the onCompleted method be executed? After the data has been downloaded or after all the subscribe have been executed?

Comment: On the logs, I tracked that onCompleted already executed, but the data continues to be recorded in the sqlite.

Comment: onCompleted executes only after all tasks emit onCompleted. [Documentation link](https://static.javadoc.io/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.2.1/rx/Completable.html#merge(rx.Completable...))

Comment: I think it's because you put your fetched data into db asynchronously. `doOnNext` operator synchronously executes its block, so it just starts db operation and completes. If you want to wait until db request completed - wrap it into `Observable` and chain it with `flatMap` (instead of `doOnNext`)

Comment: How i can wrap my code for save in db to observable? Can give a short example?

Comment: Here is nice article about creating Observables - [link](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-an-observable-in-rxjava)